# Status code 200 OK vs 301 Moved Permanently for res.redirect()

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, http-status-codes

I am designing REST API with a single page design which is achieved by using .ejs to render a specific view.

Once a POST route has been called in my node.js file the final response is `res.redirect(?, '/');` so that .ejs can display the right HTML content with respect to the data provided by the POST route.

My question is, should I be sending a status code of `200 OK` to notify that the action has been successfully completed i.e. `res.redirect(200, '/');`, or should I instead be sending a status code of `301 Moved Permanently` to signify the redirection/refreshing of the page i.e. `res.redirect(301, '/');`?

Example of POST route:

```
app.post('/example', (req, res) => {
   ...
   res.redirect(?, '/');
});
```

**NOTE:** even before the POST route is called, the user is at the root `/`, hence `res.redirect('/');` simply refreshes the page.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, this is likely a function of how you interpret the specs for [each HTTP status code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Comment: Yes, which status code would be most suitable for my example?

Comment: 200 is your status man. use that!

Comment: Use 301 when you've changed a static url or your whole web app alltogether